# Getting rid of white space on top by setting padding

Tags: html, css

I'm working on building a side navigation bar and run into a layout question. Basically, there will be a slice of white space on the very top unless I add `padding: 1rem;` to `main`. Could you please tell me why this is?

```css
:root {
    font-size: 16px;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
}

main {
    margin-left: 5rem;
    /*this line is necessary for eliminating the white space on top*/
    padding: 1rem;
}

nav {
    position: fixed;
    width: 5rem;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <nav>
        <div class="nav-item">
            <a href="#">this is a link</a>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item">
            <a href="#">this is a link</a>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item">
            <a href="#">this is a link</a>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item">
            <a href="#">this is a link</a>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item">
            <a href="#">this is a link</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <main>
        <main class="main">
            <h1>CSS is Cool</h1>
            <p>
              I'm baby kale chips affogato ennui lumbersexual, williamsburg paleo quinoa
              iceland normcore tumeric. Kitsch coloring book retro, seitan schlitz
              tattooed biodiesel vexillologist neutra. Synth mumblecore deep v, umami
              selfies normcore gluten-free snackwave. Seitan ramps drinking vinegar
              venmo keytar, humblebrag VHS post-ironic tacos godard pour-over.
            </p>
            <p>
              Sartorial kogi taxidermy, kickstarter synth yr irony ennui everyday carry
              retro helvetica stumptown cloud bread squid echo park. Etsy cloud bread
              sartorial quinoa tacos beard mumblecore shaman tumblr pop-up. Twee retro
              fingerstache af helvetica pabst 8-bit leggings taiyaki portland ramps tbh
              tumblr vinyl. Neutra humblebrag bushwick portland subway tile plaid, offal
              scenester flexitarian cliche squid small batch palo santo. Palo santo meh
              adaptogen +1 3 wolf moon, listicle brunch ethical fanny pack everyday
              carry fam. Offal fingerstache taxidermy, man bun venmo PBR&amp;B helvetica
              thundercats everyday carry tote bag artisan cray wolf jianbing.
            </p>
            <p>
              Taxidermy thundercats whatever austin. VHS helvetica ethical, dreamcatcher
              enamel pin YOLO shabby chic locavore man bun crucifix pabst chillwave
              pop-up vegan. Air plant mlkshk ethical echo park tumeric, whatever
              crucifix godard scenester locavore pork belly yuccie vape. +1 gochujang
              put a bird on it, pork belly whatever selfies vaporware occupy banh mi
              normcore VHS. Cornhole normcore hashtag tilde. Hell of yr try-hard DIY raw
              denim banjo, enamel pin irony polaroid copper mug tofu. Dreamcatcher lomo
              literally 90's before they sold out, 3 wolf moon banh mi seitan chambray
              cliche offal tote bag occupy pug.
            </p>
            <p>
              Post-ironic hot chicken salvia yr yuccie ugh cold-pressed keffiyeh franzen
              viral taxidermy mustache slow-carb crucifix vape. Taiyaki yuccie hell of
              tacos PBR&amp;B, kitsch meggings tbh truffaut kickstarter mixtape af kogi.
              Fingerstache vegan tofu waistcoat gentrify cray. Drinking vinegar 3 wolf
              moon health goth craft beer master cleanse. Letterpress health goth 8-bit
              chillwave craft beer brooklyn. Chicharrones master cleanse 8-bit,
              mumblecore copper mug messenger bag poutine lomo kale chips flannel. Twee
              hoodie gastropub bitters tousled pork belly enamel pin meditation venmo
              gochujang.
            </p>
            <p>
              Next level selfies cronut ethical. Tofu tumblr you probably haven't heard
              of them, man braid literally forage swag chillwave. Pug yr flannel
              tumeric. Coloring book yr chillwave snackwave, shoreditch shaman gentrify
              typewriter tumeric DIY copper mug small batch. Scenester waistcoat YOLO
              hexagon kombucha poke 8-bit meditation. Selvage scenester forage
              williamsburg. Hoodie fingerstache tacos mustache, hashtag quinoa next
              level sartorial craft beer retro disrupt lo-fi.
            </p>
            <p>
              YOLO twee keytar farm-to-table flexitarian cardigan polaroid lumbersexual
              adaptogen drinking vinegar echo park dreamcatcher. Brunch shoreditch
              dreamcatcher iPhone knausgaard plaid edison bulb letterpress ethical yr
              fanny pack. Typewriter portland woke glossier cronut, post-ironic migas
              gentrify letterpress cray brunch lyft 8-bit master cleanse. Pitchfork
              thundercats organic pour-over unicorn lomo.
            </p>
            <p>
              Ugh yr tacos aesthetic everyday carry, tumeric selvage cliche skateboard.
              Wolf truffaut enamel pin vexillologist poutine. Hoodie roof party pabst,
              cardigan letterpress af disrupt +1 subway tile chillwave live-edge
              meggings next level readymade. Master cleanse gentrify hashtag, stumptown
              fam single-origin coffee occupy dreamcatcher air plant viral vexillologist
              enamel pin meggings. Tumblr chambray pickled microdosing austin scenester
              green juice.
            </p>
            <p>
              Austin four dollar toast church-key, vaporware hoodie edison bulb jean
              shorts sustainable williamsburg plaid helvetica scenester lomo humblebrag.
              Meditation tumblr kickstarter ennui williamsburg taiyaki pabst pour-over.
              8-bit godard cred, chillwave enamel pin skateboard you probably haven't
              heard of them. Meditation before they sold out single-origin coffee swag
              try-hard jianbing slow-carb shaman leggings. Palo santo shabby chic
              whatever man bun. Master cleanse wayfarers single-origin coffee pork belly
              cronut, normcore cliche jianbing before they sold out tousled shabby chic
              af pop-up gentrify. Direct trade la croix vexillologist jianbing,
              flexitarian selvage try-hard stumptown polaroid shaman wayfarers poke
              ramps food truck swag.
            </p>
            <p>
              Pok pok lumbersexual wayfarers, direct trade leggings poutine truffaut
              kitsch. Seitan aesthetic master cleanse squid coloring book banh mi YOLO
              vegan locavore vexillologist readymade next level pop-up edison bulb.
              Selvage knausgaard literally, quinoa photo booth 3 wolf moon microdosing
              freegan yuccie. Truffaut gentrify lomo put a bird on it waistcoat. Ugh
              austin distillery, tbh actually pork belly snackwave artisan mixtape
              quinoa vexillologist pok pok polaroid listicle readymade.
            </p>
            <p>
              Hammock letterpress prism dreamcatcher truffaut shabby chic vice
              cold-pressed. Franzen pug fashion axe before they sold out, tumblr irony
              kogi actually af bushwick banh mi. Snackwave bicycle rights tofu
              dreamcatcher tote bag pour-over meditation raw denim fanny pack. Pop-up
              retro taiyaki meditation twee gastropub VHS etsy. Semiotics gochujang
              street art normcore, edison bulb farm-to-table pour-over taxidermy
              brooklyn.
            </p>
            <p>
              I'm baby kale chips affogato ennui lumbersexual, williamsburg paleo quinoa
              iceland normcore tumeric. Kitsch coloring book retro, seitan schlitz
              tattooed biodiesel vexillologist neutra. Synth mumblecore deep v, umami
              selfies normcore gluten-free snackwave. Seitan ramps drinking vinegar
              venmo keytar, humblebrag VHS post-ironic tacos godard pour-over.
            </p>
            <p>
              Sartorial kogi taxidermy, kickstarter synth yr irony ennui everyday carry
              retro helvetica stumptown cloud bread squid echo park. Etsy cloud bread
              sartorial quinoa tacos beard mumblecore shaman tumblr pop-up. Twee retro
              fingerstache af helvetica pabst 8-bit leggings taiyaki portland ramps tbh
              tumblr vinyl. Neutra humblebrag bushwick portland subway tile plaid, offal
              scenester flexitarian cliche squid small batch palo santo. Palo santo meh
              adaptogen +1 3 wolf moon, listicle brunch ethical fanny pack everyday
              carry fam. Offal fingerstache taxidermy, man bun venmo PBR&amp;B helvetica
              thundercats everyday carry tote bag artisan cray wolf jianbing.
            </p>
            <p>
              Taxidermy thundercats whatever austin. VHS helvetica ethical, dreamcatcher
              enamel pin YOLO shabby chic locavore man bun crucifix pabst chillwave
              pop-up vegan. Air plant mlkshk ethical echo park tumeric, whatever
              crucifix godard scenester locavore pork belly yuccie vape. +1 gochujang
              put a bird on it, pork belly whatever selfies vaporware occupy banh mi
              normcore VHS. Cornhole normcore hashtag tilde. Hell of yr try-hard DIY raw
              denim banjo, enamel pin irony polaroid copper mug tofu. Dreamcatcher lomo
              literally 90's before they sold out, 3 wolf moon banh mi seitan chambray
              cliche offal tote bag occupy pug.
            </p>
            <p>
              Post-ironic hot chicken salvia yr yuccie ugh cold-pressed keffiyeh franzen
              viral taxidermy mustache slow-carb crucifix vape. Taiyaki yuccie hell of
              tacos PBR&amp;B, kitsch meggings tbh truffaut kickstarter mixtape af kogi.
              Fingerstache vegan tofu waistcoat gentrify cray. Drinking vinegar 3 wolf
              moon health goth craft beer master cleanse. Letterpress health goth 8-bit
              chillwave craft beer brooklyn. Chicharrones master cleanse 8-bit,
              mumblecore copper mug messenger bag poutine lomo kale chips flannel. Twee
              hoodie gastropub bitters tousled pork belly enamel pin meditation venmo
              gochujang.
            </p>
            <p>
              Next level selfies cronut ethical. Tofu tumblr you probably haven't heard
              of them, man braid literally forage swag chillwave. Pug yr flannel
              tumeric. Coloring book yr chillwave snackwave, shoreditch shaman gentrify
              typewriter tumeric DIY copper mug small batch. Scenester waistcoat YOLO
              hexagon kombucha poke 8-bit meditation. Selvage scenester forage
              williamsburg. Hoodie fingerstache tacos mustache, hashtag quinoa next
              level sartorial craft beer retro disrupt lo-fi.
            </p>
            <p>
              YOLO twee keytar farm-to-table flexitarian cardigan polaroid lumbersexual
              adaptogen drinking vinegar echo park dreamcatcher. Brunch shoreditch
              dreamcatcher iPhone knausgaard plaid edison bulb letterpress ethical yr
              fanny pack. Typewriter portland woke glossier cronut, post-ironic migas
              gentrify letterpress cray brunch lyft 8-bit master cleanse. Pitchfork
              thundercats organic pour-over unicorn lomo.
            </p>
            <p>
              Ugh yr tacos aesthetic everyday carry, tumeric selvage cliche skateboard.
              Wolf truffaut enamel pin vexillologist poutine. Hoodie roof party pabst,
              cardigan letterpress af disrupt +1 subway tile chillwave live-edge
              meggings next level readymade. Master cleanse gentrify hashtag, stumptown
              fam single-origin coffee occupy dreamcatcher air plant viral vexillologist
              enamel pin meggings. Tumblr chambray pickled microdosing austin scenester
              green juice.
            </p>
            <p>
              Austin four dollar toast church-key, vaporware hoodie edison bulb jean
              shorts sustainable williamsburg plaid helvetica scenester lomo humblebrag.
              Meditation tumblr kickstarter ennui williamsburg taiyaki pabst pour-over.
              8-bit godard cred, chillwave enamel pin skateboard you probably haven't
              heard of them. Meditation before they sold out single-origin coffee swag
              try-hard jianbing slow-carb shaman leggings. Palo santo shabby chic
              whatever man bun. Master cleanse wayfarers single-origin coffee pork belly
              cronut, normcore cliche jianbing before they sold out tousled shabby chic
              af pop-up gentrify. Direct trade la croix vexillologist jianbing,
              flexitarian selvage try-hard stumptown polaroid shaman wayfarers poke
              ramps food truck swag.
            </p>
            <p>
              Pok pok lumbersexual wayfarers, direct trade leggings poutine truffaut
              kitsch. Seitan aesthetic master cleanse squid coloring book banh mi YOLO
              vegan locavore vexillologist readymade next level pop-up edison bulb.
              Selvage knausgaard literally, quinoa photo booth 3 wolf moon microdosing
              freegan yuccie. Truffaut gentrify lomo put a bird on it waistcoat. Ugh
              austin distillery, tbh actually pork belly snackwave artisan mixtape
              quinoa vexillologist pok pok polaroid listicle readymade.
            </p>
            <p>
              Hammock letterpress prism dreamcatcher truffaut shabby chic vice
              cold-pressed. Franzen pug fashion axe before they sold out, tumblr irony
              kogi actually af bushwick banh mi. Snackwave bicycle rights tofu
              dreamcatcher tote bag pour-over meditation raw denim fanny pack. Pop-up
              retro taiyaki meditation twee gastropub VHS etsy. Semiotics gochujang
              street art normcore, edison bulb farm-to-table pour-over taxidermy
              brooklyn.
            </p>
          </main>
    </main>
    
</body>
```

Comment: top:0 to fixed ..

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

This should get rid of the excess white space.

Comment: I thought the OP said ***Could you please tell me why this is*** not how to fix it. And you even didn't mention that.